# Dragging out of an NSTableView - My head is spinning

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, nstableview, mousedown

I am trying to make my `ETXTableView` (a subclass of `NSTableView`) a dragging source. It has a controller, and I pointed the nextResponder of the `ETXTableView` to the controller. My problem is that whenever I put in a call to `[super mouseDown:...]` (so that row selection etc. is handled), my dragging does not occur.

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [self.nextResponder mouseDown:theEvent];
    [super mouseDown:theEvent];
}
```

The `mouseDragged:` in the controller is never called. When I take out the `[super MouseDown:theEvent]` there is no problem with dragging but I cannot select rows.

It seems like I am fighting the system. Is there an easier way to do this? Perhaps with the DraggingSource protocol?

Comment: You should be handling row selection changes in `NSTableViewDelegate`'s `tableViewSelectionDidChange:`

Comment: This where I am at, now. I tried avoiding that at first, because there are many ways that the selection could have changed (modifications to the table, key presses etc). Thanks for pointing me back in the right direction.